# Conect Bixolon printer to a router and access it by IP

Tags: router, ip, printer

I have a Bixolon 350 POS printer connected to my router but I can not access it .

my router IP 192.168.1.1
but the printer default ip : 
192.168.192.123
gateway : 192.168.192.254

from my pc I can not access the printer or send ping request ( timeout request).

I wan to know what I need to do to give my printer an ip address in my router, so I can access it .

the router is : Huawei HG658b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access it via their ["Net Configuration Tool"](http://www.bixolon.com/html/en/download/download_category.xhtml?ca_id=114&large_cd=0012&small_cd=0008) as explained [in the manual](http://www.bixolon.com/upload/download/manual_net%20configuration%20tool_english_rev_4_00.pdf), and adjust its IP to be in your 192.168.1.X subnet.

[image]

I'm not sure if this will detect/configure the device while it's on another subnet.

If not:

- Hook the printer directly to a computer via a network cable.
- Set the IP on the computer to be in the same subnet as the printer (ie: 192.168.192.1, 255.255.255.0).
- You should now be able to ping the printer via IP address.
- If so, then access it via their "Net Configuration Tool", and adjust its IP to be in your 192.168.1.X subnet (as shown above).
- Once that's all done, change your computer's IP back to it's original settings, plug both devices back into the network infrastructure, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi , your solutions worked with me to change the default IP. But I am still facing problem.

Comment: Hi , your solutions worked with me to change the default IP. But I am still facing problem.
Printer IP: 192.168.1.3
Gateway : 192.168.1.1
Router IP: 192.168.1.1
in router management page: I can see the printer connected the IP : 192.168.1.3 is  connected to the Printer MAC address.

but the printer still unreachable ?!

Pinging 192.168.1.3 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.2: Destination host unreachable.
..
.. etc 
Ping statistics for 192.168.1.3:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Comment: Have you confirmed the printer actually support responds to Pings?  Perhaps try taking the router (back) out of the equation, hook the printer directly to your computer via a network cable, setup the networking to match, and then try pinging it.  Otherwise, there's too many moving parts to be able to tell you why you can't' ping it.  But if the device isn't _capable_ of responding to pings, then it won't respond to pings.  You may have to check with the manufacturer to figure out if it's supposed to support ping at all...

Comment: The Problem now even  "Net Configuration Tool" could not discover the printer not just the ping issue.?!

Comment: The Problem solved , Thank you your answer is the solution.